# Uniqueness of minimum norm solution

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares

Let's state a regularized least squares problem $min_{x\in R^N}\ \  \Vert y-Ax \Vert _2 ^2\ \ +\ \delta\Vert x \Vert _2 ^2$  has a unique solution for every $\delta > 0$, and when $\delta\to0$, the regularized solution goes to the minimum norm solution of $min_{x\in R^N}\ \  \Vert x \Vert _2 ^2\ \ subject\ to\ A^TAx = A^Ty$. $A$ is a $M * N $ matrix with $rank(A) < N$. How do we prove that the minimum norm solution is always unique?

Comment: By proving it is convex.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Any hints could be given? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Convex:  Show that if you have two solutions $a$ and $b$, that $t a + (1-t) b$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$ is also a solution.